# Issue in Setting Value to @State variable in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, property-wrapper

I'm trying to set value to a `@State` variable `alertText` once a button click action is performed. However it isn't working and value in `alertText` isn't getting set.

I'm new to SwiftUI so I think I'm missing something obvious. I would appreciate any help.

```
struct ContentView: View {
@State private var showSheet = false
@State private var alertText : String = "Initial Value"

var body: some View {
    NavigationView{
        Button("Show Sheet", action: {
            alertText = "Modified Value"
            showSheet = true
        })
        .sheet(isPresented: $showSheet, content: {
            Text(alertText)
        })
        .navigationTitle("Test View")
    }
}
}
```

[image: Issue]

Comment: Add `[alertText] in` at the beginning of your sheet closure. You also may want to investigate the sheet(item:) form instead of sheet(isPresented:) which commonly runs into this issue.

Comment: @jnpdx Thank you for the comment. I'm able to make it work by wrapping `alertText ` inside an another struct and using that struct in `sheet(item:)`. By the way thank u for ur time.